# Optimal 4-input sorting network

Tags: logic, sorting

In his paper *The Bose-Nelson Sorting Problem* (1973, Chapter 15 of *A Survey of Combinatorial theory* on page 163 available on [Google books](https://books.google.fr/books?hl=en&lr=&id=U8HSBQAAQBAJ)), Knuth says that the optimal bound of 5 comparators for a 4-input sorting network comes from an "elementary information-theoretic argument".

Information theory is not a part of my tool set, yet I have to prove this result.

---

I have managed to construct a 5-comparator network that solves the problem, and am trying to prove that any 4-comparator network does not work.

I have managed to prove that 3 comparators are needed if we want the top output to be the max of all inputs. In fact, for each input, at least three comparators are needed, but I cannot prove that they are different for each output.

Comment: "In his paper, ..." What paper? Please edit your post to include a reference or link to the paper.

Comment: I added a reference as well as a link to said paper available online. Sorry, I didn't realize it might interest some people.

Comment: It isn't that I think it is particularly _interesting_, but more that knowing what paper you are reading could be very _helpful to answer_ your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that there were a network using only 4 comparators. The correct order of the inputs can be recovered by known the result of all 4 comparisons, since given these results, you can simulate the effect of the network. However, there are only $2^4 = 16$ possible results of the comparisons, whereas there are $4! = 24$ possible orders of inputs.

Comment: Why does there have to be more possible results of comparisons than order of inputs possible? I feel like this is the same argument as advanced by Knuth, saying there must be over $log_2(n!)$ comparisons.

Comment: Given the outputs of all comparisons, you should be able to deduce the order of the inputs, since given the outputs, you can sort the inputs.

Comment: I get the gist of it, but how does one formalize the fact that a sorting algorithm should be able to 'un-sort' back to the original order?

Comment: If you run all swaps in reverse, then you are unsorting the sorted version to the original order.